# mongodb 2.4 full text search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, full-text-search, node-mongodb-native

In mongo shell I can do this

```
db.collection.runCommand( 'text', { search: 'query' } )
```

And how can I get this with mongodb-native and node.js?

I tried to do something like this

```
db.executeDbCommand( 'text', { search:'query' }, function(e, o) {
    if (e) {
        callback(e)
    }
    else callback(o)
});
```

and it's failed

Comment: I think you can follow this link [here][1]



  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070233/runcommand-equivalent-for-nodejs-native-mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is pretty simple

```
exports.search = function(query, callback) {
db.command({ text: 'collectionName', search: query }, function(e, o) {
    if (e) {
        console.log(e, 'error')
    }
    else callback(o)
});
}
```

And in callback

```
DB.search(query, function(o){
    if (o) {
        console.log(o.results);
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems like 'limit' is also working but I can't make the 'skip' working.