# Is it possible to use native mongodb commands in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently working on a project using mongodb as the database, it has node.js on the server and is using the mongoose package, i was wondering if it was possible to use native mongodb commands in mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the node.js mongodb driver directly rather than mongoose as they have done in this question: [runCommand equivalent for nodejs-native-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070233/runcommand-equivalent-for-nodejs-native-mongodb)

Namely:

```
this.db.command({ ... }, function(err, cb){ ... });
```