# MongoDB NodeJS > db.createRole is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using the "Node.js MongoDB Driver API", and I was hoping to convert my database initialisation scripts to NodeJS.

I can't [find any admin commands](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Admin.html#command) (e.g. `db.createRole()`, `db.grantPrivilegesToRole()`). Do these functions exist somewhere else? OR is there some alternative workaround I can use? (e.g. `runCommand`)

Here is the full code snippet.

**db_test.js**

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/admin')
  .then(client => client.db('admin').admin())
  .then(db => {
    return db.createRole({
      role: 'SOME_ROLE',
      privileges: [],
      roles: []
    })
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Success!')
    process.exit(0)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error! - ' + err.message)
    process.exit(99)
  })
```

**Output:**

> Error! - db.createRole is not a function

**NodeJS Library:** [`"mongodb": "3.1.4"`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases/tag/v3.1.4)

**Docker Server:** [`image: mongo:3.4.2`](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/)

Disclaimer: I've also asked this question in [GoogleGroups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-mongodb-native/UoZwKVlSeFU).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.createRole` is not a function. Try doing it like this:

```js
db.command( { createRole: 'SOME_ROLE', privileges: [], roles: [] } )
```

#### References:

- [Mongodb Native API](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Admin.html#command) ([`command` is the native equivalent of `runCommand`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070233/runcommand-equivalent-for-nodejs-native-mongodb))
- [Mongodb Reference Docs > createRole](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createRole/#dbcmd.createRole)

Answer (score 0):

You got error because db is not defined in this line : `.then(dbAdmin => db.createRole(...))`

Try like this :

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/admin',(err,db) =>{

    if (err) return console.log(err);

    db.createRole(...)

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Abderrahim, not quite. That was my mistake (bad copy and pasting code). I've attached the full source - same issue.